# The difference of two discrete uniform variables taken modulo. Is still uniform?

Tags: distributions, uniform-distribution

I have a uniform distribution that generates from the $\mathbb{Z}_q$ (so I have integers from the interval [$-q/2$, $q/2$). Then I subtract one from the other and take the result modulo $q$ (so again I have an integer from the interval above).

How to prove (or disprove) that the resulting distribution remains uniform in  $\mathbb{Z}_q$?

Comment: why don't you test it ?

Comment: Because the distribution of the first draw is invariant under the additive action of the group (a shift) and is independent of the second draw, so must the difference be invariant. That means nothing other than that its distribution is uniform. This argument generalizes the question, because it shows *it is immaterial how the second value is chosen,* provided only that the two draws are independent. As an extreme example, the second value may be a constant.

Comment: If this is for some subject, could you please add the self-study tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 0.